# Angular Data Grid: Master / Detail | when i click on the arrow it doesn't get the id value only when i cycle on the line

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way that when I click to expand it already clicks on the line?

[image]
I'm trying to get the id of the line that is expanded. The goal is that when I reflash the screen it brings the last one that was opened, opened.